# Reshape by Certain Name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a cell-matrix like the below,

- the first column: A, B, C
- the second column: A, B, D
- the third column: 1, 1, 1

Which means that A and A has 1 unit, B and B has 1 unit and C and D has one unit

How can I conveniently create the following matrix (mat) in matlab?

```
     [Name,A,B,C,D
      A,1,NA,NA,NA
mat = B,NA,1,NA,NA
      C,NA,NA,NA,NA
      D,NA,NA,NA,1]
```

I think I can use a loop to achieve that, but actually the dimension is much larger than the example able. How can I do that?

A, B, C, D here are characters, if the matrix cannot contain both numeric and character, I can remove the first column and the first row in mat. Also actually the first matrix containing the relationship of A, B, C, D is a 3*3 cell.

Comment: Are `A, B, C, D` characters or actual values? You cannot mix numerical and string values in a standard MATLAB array. You should also remove the [tag:resharper] tag as this question has nothing to do with Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Desired output can be produced:

```
mycell = {...
'A' , 'B' , 'C'
'A' , 'B' , 'D'
1   , 1   , 1};
[U, ~, IDX] = unique(mycell(1:2,:));
IDX = reshape(IDX,2,[]).';
mat = accumarray(IDX,[mycell{3,:}],[],[],NA);
```

so `U` is names of rows/columns

`IDX` shows indices of rows and columns of `mat` that contain non `NA` values

`accumarray` is the function that can convert indices and values to desired matrix

Now you can access elements of `mat` by numeric indices i.e. `mat(1,3)` that represent relationship of `A` and `C`

If you want to work with character indices instead of numeric ones you can do this:

```
index=cell2struct(num2cell(1:numel(U)),U,2);
mat(index.A, index.C)
```

`index` is a struct that maps characters to numbers. Also you can use `index` this way:

```
mat(index.('A'), index.('C'))
```